# Is possible to apply an effect to an image from command line?

Tags: linux, bash, image-processing

I wanted to know if it is possible to apply an effect to an image distortion, such as fish-eye effect but from the command line (ie, do not use gimp)

Or distort an image (a photo) to deform the face and make it funny, but everything from the command line ..

I hope you can help me!
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`ImageMagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Comment: Take a look: [General Distortion Techniques with ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#summary)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at imagemagick.  It is a powerful tool to convert and manipulate images and has a command line interface too.